# index issue while creating prediction

Tags: python

Need help, I am quite new to panda and sci kit. I am getting index error with the following code. Please let me know how do I add Index to the column mentioned here. Error is coming from  prediction area

```
# get the dependent variable
Y_COLS = ["Trip_distance"]

# Independent variable columns
X_COLS = ["precipitation"]

# Number of trees
TREES = 15

# Set dependent variable
y = df_out[Y_COLS].values


# Set independent variable
X = df_out[X_COLS].values

make an array variable for y

y1 = y.ravel()
y= np.array(y1).astype(int)



# Prepare and train random forest model
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=TREES)
clf.fit(X, y)

# Make prediction. This is needed for the chi-square test.
df = dataJun[(dataJun.U_manhattan==1)]
y = df[Y_COLS].values
X = df[X_COLS].values
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
y2 = y - y_pred

Error :     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sajith/PycharmProjects/NYCTaxi/Test.py", line 88, in <module>
    X = df[X_COLS].values
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['precipitation'] not in index"
```

Comment: What is `print(df_out.columns)` printing?

Comment: columns are showing and this precipitation column is also one of the column. But the issue is at the end. When i assign X=df[X_COLS].values, then this error is showing

Comment: Please paste the output for `print(df_out.columns)` here.

Comment: Index([u'VendorID', u'lpep_pickup_datetime', u'Lpep_dropoff_datetime',
        u'Dropoff_latitude',
       u'Passenger_count', u'Trip_distance', u'Fare_amount', u'Extra',
       u'MTA_tax', u'Tip_amount', u'Tolls_amount', u'Ehail_fee',
       u'improvement_surcharge', u'Total_amount', u'Payment_type',
       u'Trip_type ', u'Pickup_dt', u'date', u'maximum temperature',
       u'minimum temperature', u'averagetemperature', u'precipitation',
       u'snowfall', u'snow depth', u'pdate'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Okay, try `X = df_out.loc[:, u'precipitation']`?

Comment: I will try this. but before that it was a wonderful tip. i had df_out and dataJun data frame. I only had precipitation in the df_out. i am going to add this in datajun now. give me a moment. that should be the issue i assume

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is settled. As i mentioned i had two data frames. One of them didnt had precipation. Thanks again for your help. That was wonderful.

Comment: No worries. ;-)